# БД не отображается в обозревателе SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Программа работает, сохраняет в БД и достает данные из, в вкладке Обозреватель SQL Server не отображается. Как и где можно ее найти?

Comment: Смотрите строку соединения вашей программы, там все написано

Comment: @tym32167 именно, там написан каталог, но его нет в Обозревателе

Comment: там же есть и сервер. Вы его выбирали в обозревателе?

Comment: @tym32167 да, (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB и в строке такой же

Comment: Тогда скрин в студию, что и где у вас должно, но не отображается

Comment: @tym32167 добавил